# Is there a way to have rotation metadata in a GeoTIFF file?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff

I'm new to GIS. I need to print a georeferenced image into my geoserver. I already have the stack configured to print GeoTIFF images into the geoserver and it works.

Although, I would like to print the GeoTIFF with a configured rotation. Is there a way to store a rotation into GeoTIFF tags and use it with geoserver ? 
In other words, I don't want to change the raster but only the way to print it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might depend on your CRS but you can try to use QGIS or GDAL to transform the geotiff and add the rotation there OR perhaps more easy: create a new .tfw file and add the rotation there.

There is a related question which it tries to implement what I'm saying: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131465/gdal-rotate-dem

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found what I needed in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/131502) of the question you shared. Using a .twf (aka [WorldFile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file)) and the rotate properties do the trick. However, I had to do the math in order to have a correct rotated image. I haven't found library doing that, but I haven't search long though.